# Cucumber-serenity not inject Steps

Tags: cucumber, bdd, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I´m using cucumber-selenium to run some integration tests. I manage to create the feature file and the Test class. But once that I´m in my Give method I see that the ScenarioSteps(ProjectMemberSteps) class that I define to talk with the object page is null.
I was expecting to be injected like JBehave does.

```
public class OrderTest extends StepsLibrary {

    @Steps ProjectMemberSteps projectManager;//This one is null

    @Before
    public void beforeScenarios() throws Exception {
       initializeDemoUIServer();
     }
    @Given("I open the login page")
    public void openLoginPage(){
        projectManager.openLoginPage();
    }
   }
```

This is the Scenario runner class for the test

```
           /**
   * Serenity story for login.
     */
  @RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features/order/order.feature",
    glue = Order.BEHAVIOUR_PACKAGE)
    public class Order {
    public static final String BEHAVIOUR_PACKAGE =    "com.behaviour.steps.serenity";
    }
```

This is class ProjectMemberSteps is under steps/serenity/ as the documentation suggest. 
I´m using Maven, and the libraries that I´m using are

```
          <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.47</version>
    </dependency>
```

Anyway this particular test I´m running with the IDE and not through Maven, but I was expecting that "ProjectMemberSteps" would be inject as JBehave use to do.

Any idea what´s wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also a newbie. I don't see any problem with your OrderTest.java class except it is unnecessarily extending a class called StepsLibrary. In Java-Cucumber, I don't extend any other class. Only exception is When
StepDefinition file(your OrderTest.java) delegates method calls to xxxxSteps.java class and which in turn delegates to xxxPageObject.java (which MUST extend PageObject class from Serenity `import net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject`;)

I assume Before annotation is to repeat a scenario. Instead another alternative is Background keyword to be used in the feature file itself. I don't claim any advantage with this though.

Per me, Your Test Runner class should only give the package in which xxxxStepDefinitions.java resides, simply like `glue = {"stepdefinitions"},` curly braces are optional I believe.

The rest looks perfectly OK to me. Including defining

```
@Steps ProjectMemberSteps projectManager;
```

Try one more time.